# When I append list of tuples to another list it becomes empty

Tags: python, arrays, append

When I try to add list of tuples to another list it becomes empty.

```
tagged_sentences_list = []
for i in range (len(sentences)):
    length_sentences = len(sentences[i].split(" "))

    del words_in_the_sentence[:]
    del tagged_words[:]

    for j in range (length_sentences):
        length_words_in_sentence = len(sentences[i].split(" ")[j].split("/")[1:])

        part_of_the_speech = sentences[i].split(" ")[j].split("/")[1:]
        word = sentences[i].split(" ")[j].split("/")[:1]
        words_in_the_sentence.append(word)

        zipped = zip(word,part_of_the_speech)
        tagged_words.append(zipped)

    tagged_sentences_list.append(tagged_words)
```

Exactly in this line:

```
  tagged_sentences_list.append(tagged_words)
```

Terminal prints

```
[[]]
```

I want to append lists of tuples to another list. So I would have:

```
[[(a,b),(c,d)], [(d,e)]]
```

Any of you have any idea why? Thanks

Comment: `del tagged_words[:]` You're deleting the reference to it. You'll have to use `copy` to create new lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`del tagged_words[:]` empties the list, yes.

You have **one** list object that you keep filling and emptying, and you add references to another list. You are *not* creating copies here:

```
tagged_sentences_list.append(tagged_words)
```

Create new list objects:

```
tagged_sentences_list = []
for i in range (len(sentences)):
    length_sentences = len(sentences[i].split(" "))

    words_in_the_sentence = []
    tagged_words = []

    for j in range (length_sentences):
        length_words_in_sentence = len(sentences[i].split(" ")[j].split("/")[1:])

        part_of_the_speech = sentences[i].split(" ")[j].split("/")[1:]
        word = sentences[i].split(" ")[j].split("/")[:1]
        words_in_the_sentence.append(word)

        zipped = zip(word,part_of_the_speech)
        tagged_words.append(zipped)

    tagged_sentences_list.append(tagged_words)
```

Python names are just references; you may want to read up on how Python's memory model works, I strongly recommend [Ned Batchelder's *Facts and myths about Python names and values*](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Your code is doing a lot of redundant splitting too. Use the fact that Python `for` loops are [*for each* constructs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop); there is no need to generate an index when you can just loop over the list itself:

```
tagged_sentences_list = []
for sentence in sentences:
    tagged_words = []

    for word in sentence.split(' '):
        parts = word.split('/')[:2]
        tagged_words.append(parts)

tagged_sentences_list.append(tagged_words)
```

Note that there is no need to use `zip()`; all you do is re-combine the first and second element of the `/` split result.

If you were to use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), that could be further reduced to:

```
tagged_sentences_list = [
    [word.split('/')[:2] for word in sentence.split(' ')]
    for sentence in sentences]
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's proper solution! Have a lovely day, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tagged_sentences_list.append(tagged_words[:])
```

Or...

```
import copy
tagged_sentences_list.append(copy.copy(tagged_words))
```

If you're on python3, you may also try

```
tagged_sentences_list.append(tagged_words.copy())
```

What your current code is doing is, appending the list to the bigger list, and then clearing it using `del tagged_words[:]`.

Now, since the references are the same, you end up clearing the contents of what you stored inside the bigger list too.

Observe:

```
>>> x = []
>>> y = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
>>> x.append(y)
>>> id(x[0])
4433923464
>>> id(y)
4433923464
>>> del y[:]
>>> x
[[]]
```

You've gotten an empty list because you appended and then cleared the original. Now, this is what happens when you make a copy of the list:

```
>>> x = []
>>> y = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
>>> x.append(y[:])
>>> del y[:]
>>> x
[[(1, 2), (3, 4)]]
```